# Action after failed coded ui test

Tags: c#, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am using multiple c# Ordered tests on daily runs. Each test requires a revert to a snapshot so all data and changes are lost (which is ok for me)

But... sometimes the test fails and all the info is lost. Visual studio provides a good explanation and a screenshot (very usefull)

My question : Is there a way or function to implement that if the test fails, some files(log / crash) are copied to a network location (hard coded function or link to a bat/script file or something in playback function)
I have tried with try catch options in my tests but than you lose the good info you get from visual studio. If there is no way to achieve this I will go back to the try catch

Regards

as requested some code:

This is a TestMethod i use:

```
//playback options + delay
Logging.playback();
Try{
Mouse.Click(uITaskListItems);
foreach (WinControl TaskList in uITaskListItems.GetChildren())
{
 if (TaskList.Name.Contains(Variables.TaskItem1))
 {
   Mouse.Click(TaskList, MouseButtons.Right);
   Mouse.Click(uIListMonitor);
   break;
  }
 }
}catch(Exception ex){
Logging.Log(ex.Message);
Assert.Fail();
```

And playback options

```
private static void Playback_PlaybackError(object sender, PlaybackErrorEventArgs e)
{
   // Wait a second
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   // Retry the failed test operation
   e.Result = PlaybackErrorOptions.Retry;
 }
 //playback options
 public static void playback()
 {
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.MatchExactHierarchy = true;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.SmartMatchOptions = SmartMatchOptions.Control;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.SmartMatchOptions = SmartMatchOptions.TopLevelWindow;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.SmartMatchOptions = SmartMatchOptions.None;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 2000;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.ShouldSearchFailFast = true;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.ThinkTimeMultiplier = 2;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyTimeout = 2000;
   Playback.PlaybackError -= Playback_PlaybackError;
   Playback.PlaybackError += Playback_PlaybackError;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.DelayBetweenActions = 300;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your codes?

Comment: I'm not sure it might be usefull to add code.
this is a test method I use

Mouse.Click(uITaskListItems);
            foreach (WinControl TaskList in uITaskListItems.GetChildren())
            {
                if (TaskList.Name.Contains(Variables.TaskItem1))
                {
                    Mouse.Click(TaskList, MouseButtons.Right);
                    Mouse.Click(uIListMonitor);

                    break;
                }
            }

Comment: Sorry, I mean the `try` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a `[TestCleanup]` method that will be executed after every test. The code might be based on the following.

```
[TestCleanup()]
public void MyTestCleanup()
{
    switch (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome)
    {
        case UnitTestOutcome.Passed:
            // Success.
            break;

        case UnitTestOutcome.Aborted:
        case UnitTestOutcome.Error:
        case UnitTestOutcome.Failed:
        case UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive:
        case UnitTestOutcome.InProgress:
        case UnitTestOutcome.Timeout:
        case UnitTestOutcome.Unknown:
            // Oh dear.
            break;

        default:
            // Should never be called.
            break;
    }
}
```

A simpler routine might use just a single `if` statement:

```
    if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed )
    {
        // Oh dear.
    }
```

Comment: i used the if statement in a test cleanup and it works the way i want it. This answer is usefull in this case even tho i learned and am using the other answer also  in some cases. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Using the Exception class you can get all the information of the error. *-"Just like what visual studio do"*

```
try
{
  //make some noise...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
     //ex.Data, ex.HelpLink, ex.HResult, ex.Messages etc..
}
```

Comment: aha. was aware of some functions about the ex output but you pointed me to something extra. so yeah will use the try catch option unless there is an other way provided. Thx for the help

Comment: You can even grab different exceptions to provide different functionality.  For example, if an Assertion fails, then log it as a normal failed test case, and likewise if a control can't be found, then catch the UITestControlNotFound exception for a specific set of actions when that occurs (Maybe save a screen shot of the page for your logs or something).